# ¿Como pasar un ArrayList a las Etiqutas y Datos de un Chart JS?

Tags: javascript

soy nuevo en esto de la web y me encontré con este problema que no logro entender como hacer para que funcione (por eso me uní a ustedes que son los que saben). Me explico, tengo un arralist y quiero pasar estos datos -Nombre de moneda y Valor del Día- a un gráfico Chart JS. Esto esta en JSP
Desde ya, muy agradecido:

Al inciar el JSP:

```
<%@page import="java.util.ArrayList"%>
<%@page import="Modelo.Indicadores"%>
<%
ArrayList<Indicadores> listIndicadores = (ArrayList<Indicadores>)request.getSession().getAttribute("atrIndicadores");
if(listIndicadores == null)
{
    response.sendRedirect("error.jsp");
}
else
{%>
```

Y en el script tengo esto:

```
                        <!-- Mi 1er Grafico -->
                    <div class="w3-container w3-card w3-white w3-round w3-margin">
                        <h5><b><i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o"></i> Indicador de ventas</b></h5>
                        <canvas id="objGrafico"></canvas>
                    </div>
                    <!--  -->
                    <script>
                        var ctx = document.getElementById("objGrafico").getContext("2d");
                        var vTituloGrafico = "Indicadores Diarios";
                        var vTipoGrafico = "bar";
                        var arrEtiquetas = ["Etiq01", "Etiq02", "Etiq03", "Etiq04", "Etiq05"];//<Esto debería llegar del ArrayList
                        var arrDatos = [10, 13, 15, 18, 22];//<Esto debería llegar del ArrayList
                        //
                        //for (var vIndice = 0; vIndice < listIndicadores.size(); vIndice++)
                        //{
                        //    arrEtiquetasII[vIndice] = listIndicadores.get(vIndice).getvMoneda();
                        //    arrDatosII[vIndice] = listIndicadores.get(vIndice).getvValorCambio();
                        //}
                        //
                        var myChart = new Chart(ctx,{
                            type: vTipoGrafico,
                            data:{
                                labels:arrEtiquetas,
                                datasets:[{
                                        label:vTituloGrafico,
                                        data:arrDatos,
                                        backgroundColor:[
                                            'rgb(66, 134, 244)',
                                           'rgb(74, 135, 72,0.8)',
                                            'rgb(229, 89, 50,0.6)'
                                        ]
                                }]
                            },
                            options:{
                                scales:{
                                    yAxes:[{
                                            ticks:{
                                                beginAtZero:true
                                            }
                                    }]
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    </script>
```

Espero que esta vez este bien explicado :D

---

Amigos!!!,

Encontré este vídeo, pero no se como hacerlo con el código que tengo!!!

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ki_CoQK8cAQ

Comment: No queda muy claro lo que quieres conseguir: La clase ArrayList es de Java, no de Javascript, y tu código parece ser parte de un JSP. Supongo que en tu HTML podrías añadir los datos de tu lista en un formato que sea legible para Javascript, por ejemplo crean una variable global de tipo array que contenga objetos equivalentes a la clase Indicadores

Comment: Por otro lado te recomiendo que completes el [tour] de bienvenida a SOes para que entiendas cómo esperamos que se formule una pregunta y qué es un [mcve]

Comment: Mil disculpas Don Pablo, haré lo que usted me recomienda y tratare de explicar mejor lo que quiero hacer.

Comment: Un link a un video no nos sirve. podrias mostrar que es lo que no sabes hacer?

Comment: Tengo un arraylist<indicadores>, que pasa por variables de sesión a un JSP, y en este JSP me gustaria mostrar un grafico con los datos de este arraylist. Pero he ahi el problema, no tengo idea de como hacer que las etiquetas y la data del gráfico tome los datos que tengo en este array<>. En el video lo hace una persona pero con PHP y ya estoy de cabeza.